# Unable to send text %, &, new line with post method in volley. getting 400 Error

Tags: android, json, post, android-volley

When i am sending % & and new line character via post method in volley.
Getting 400 error.
Via hitting Postman it is successfully hitting.

Comment: share your **code**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `URLEncoder.encode(comment_text)`

```
String urlJsonObj = AppConfig.Base_Url+AppConfig.App_api+ "/addGroupsComments?group_id=" + GroupId + "&userAccessToken=" + userAccessToken + "&comment_text=" + URLEncoder.encode(comment_text);
```

then try changing it as `GET`

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            urlJsonObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
```